# app opens with url from qr code, but not from browser

Tags: android, android-intent

When i scan a qr code containing my url my app opens, but when i type my url in the browser my app doesn't start, the same is for links

i enter this url

```
myschema://ROOT/kategorie
```

my intent filter is defined in my launch activity like this

```
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:scheme="myschema"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: i just realized in firefox it works, but not in default browser and chrome, so i should figure out how they handle this

Comment: or is this only for ifrmaes ?
https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/intents?hl=de